# YARDoc (Documentation generator) for PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, documentation

Does anybody know a comparable documentation for PHP/CakePHP ?

http://yardoc.org/ makes a pretty decent looking documentation for Ruby and I'm looking for a comparable-quality looking for PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the official api generator that is used to genrate api.cakephp.org

https://github.com/cakephp/api_generator

The look of it can be customized as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Burzum's answer was correct sometime back but now api_generator project is unmaintained and they are suggesting to use [APIGen](https://github.com/ApiGen/ApiGen) or [PHPDocumentor](https://www.phpdoc.org/) instead.

I've used PHPDocumentor and it generates really nice, easy to understand API Doc.

Hope it help someone.